# Facebook photos url not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cdn

We have developed an app that fetches users facebook photos on login and we have found out that photos’ urls aren’t working anymore.
In Facebook’s documentation says nothing about images’ urls expiration.
Is there a way to get around this? How can we recover not working urls?

Comment: show us your code first. then we will be able to help.

Comment: Why do you need code? I have an image URL retrieved using facebook sdk a time ago and now this url is not working. Here you have an example url: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/10377166_10152219122631717_2481769691029326893_n.jpg?oh=7b346e64d94db956ade767169cc59982&oe=55D8352E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook photos have an ID associated with their data object. If you look for the photo by ID, then find the source of that object, you might have more luck.

If you've stored the path-specific URL for the photo without any other info, and FB has moved that source, I doubt there's anything you can do to reconnect them.

Comment: oh, I didn't get/save photo ids... I didn't know photo URLs (from CDN) were going to expire. Thank you for your help.